# Getting type of an ImplicitObjectCreationExpression

Tags: c#, new-operator, roslyn, microsoft.codeanalysis

If I have an `ImplicitObjectCreationExpression`, how can I get the type that is being created using the `SemanticModel`?

My code:

```cs
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

public static SemanticModel model;
public static ITypeSymbol GetCreationType (BaseObjectCreationExpressionSyntax boces) =>
    boces switch
    {
        ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax oces => model.GetSymbolInfo(oces.Type).Symbol!,
        ImplicitObjectCreationExpressionSyntax ioces => // ???
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzsA+CwBQACZLkHsBGArApgY2EQA9EBeRAOxwHcAKASgG4g), we can see that a statement such as

```
object x = new();
```

has a syntax tree like this (showing the `new()` part only):

[image]

The type that you want is a child of the "Operation" node, which you can get with [`SemanticModel.GetOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.semanticmodel.getoperation?view=roslyn-dotnet-3.11.0#Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_SemanticModel_GetOperation_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_SyntaxNode_System_Threading_CancellationToken_). Then you can just get its `Type`.

```
model.GetOperation(ioces).Type!
```

Comment: GetTypeInfo is a bit more direct, and won't require us to realize a the operation tree.

Answer (score 4):

You want to call GetTypeInfo instead of GetSymbolInfo.